# Calling common function from Class

Tags: dart, class, oop

I am learning dart and OOP :)

Generally its been suggested that class specific function must be called from within class. Now my question is why cant we call functions which are created outside class within multiple classes? As an example here `idCheck` function is just function which can be placed in common file and same function can be called within multiple classes which will reduce code refactoring as well as any code changes. Are there any disadvantages to this approach?

```dart
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  var a = ABC(id: 10, name: 'Robert');
  print(a.abcID(a.id));
  
  var p = PQR(id: 17);
  print(p.pqrID(p.id));
}

class ABC {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  
  ABC({required this.id, required this.name});
  
  bool abcID(int id) => idCheck(this.id);
}

class PQR {
  final int id;
  
  PQR({required this.id});
  
  bool pqrID(int id) => idCheck(this.id);
}

bool idCheck(int id) {
  return id > 10;
}
```

What are advantages and disadvantages to this approach. I see instead of one class be inherited from another and then doing super.function don't work in case of factory methods. Even we keep aside factory method and place simple functions in separate file and call them in all the class definition just like `bool abcID(int id) =\> idCheck(this.id)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to give somehow more clarified question. What I got from your question is that, you want to know what if we need the same function in   two separate classes, which have different objective. You can just create abstract class and get inheritance from that class by both of those classes. Another option is that, you can create static function inside an ordinary class and can use function of that class in both of your classes.

I didn't understand what you wanted to say by

> super.function don't work in case of factory methods.

But you can just use super.function if you extended a class. There is no it doesn't depend on factory methods.

To that question:

> why cant we call functions which are created outside class within multiple classes

The answer is, we can call functions which are created outside the class. It is also possible to create functions without classes and use them everywhere. But it's recommended to create functions inside classes, because classes define the purpose of the functions. Now it may seem somehow strange, because if you only use functions for print to see hello world it's strange to create a class for only one or two functions. But in the real projects creating classes for functions are very good and helps to make the code accurate.

I hope I answered the question.